# Way too slow wxPython application getting data from Google Spreadsheet and User input needs speed up solution

Tags: python, wxpython, user-input, google-sheets

I want to make an application that reads out city names, road names, and distances between them from a Google Spreadsheet with several worksheets.

So far I have the code bellow working right. It reads out from spreadsheet, receives input also from a user who wants to find out the road name (like Rode 60) between two cities and also the distance between them. However when I run the application it is incredibly SLOW.

I think I have a server side-user side issue, but after reading tons of documentation I'm very confused. Maybe I should consider an entirely different approach. Maybe I need to read out all the spreadsheet with gspread and to work only user side. Anyway. Now it's slow and I want to have like thousands of city's in my spreadsheet later on and probably I will put there some more data about them, like is it a country road or is it a highway, national road etc. it will take ages until it will return the result with my current code.

Please help and please mind that I'm new to python, wxPython, Google API's or to IGraph if you suggest that I should do these things with graphs. Today I did set up IGraph as well for my Python 2.7. Maybe it's the key to my problem? Please at least give me the right way, the right tutorials. I'm not expecting anyone to do the dirty job for me. Thank you in advance!!!

```
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.service
import atom.service
import gdata.spreadsheet
import atom
import gspread
import wx
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
import re
import os
import csv
import math

class laci(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'distance calculator',size=(500,500))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        test=wx.TextEntryDialog(None,"Beginning point: ",'Name of beginning point','...')
        if test.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            all1=test.GetValue()

        test2=wx.TextEntryDialog(None,"Finishing point: ",'Name of finish','...')
        if test2.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            all2=test2.GetValue()



        c = gspread.Client(auth=('......@gmail.com','.............'))
        c.login()
        # open spreadsheet
        sht=c.open_by_key('.................................')
        worksheet = sht.get_worksheet(0)

        print worksheet

        i = 1
        j = 1

        What = None



        first_col = worksheet.col_values(1)
        print first_col
        stopper = 0
        n = 3
        m = 3

        while worksheet.cell(i,1).value != None and stopper != 1:
            if worksheet.cell(i,1).value == all1:
                print all1
                stopper = 1
            else:
                i = i+1
                print i
            if worksheet.cell(i,1).value == None:
                boxy=wx.MessageDialog(None,'Wrong start point. You wanna see correct start points list?','Mistake?',wx.YES_NO)
                answer=boxy.ShowModal()
                boxy.Destroy
                if answer == 5103:
                    boxl=wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None,'Accepted Starting point names:','In case of mistake',
                                               ['City1','City2','City3','City4','City5','City6','City7','City8'])
                    if boxl.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
                        all1=boxl.GetStringSelection()
                        stopper = 0 # figyelj
                        i = 1
                        print all1
                    boxl.Destroy
                else:
                    print 'how unfortunate'
            if stopper == 1:
                sline = []
                while worksheet.cell(i,n).value != None:
                    line = worksheet.cell(i,n).value
                    sline.append(line)

                    n = n + 1
                    print sline
                    slinestr = str(sline) 


        stopper2 = 0
        print sline
        while worksheet.cell(j,1).value != None and stopper2 != 1:
            if worksheet.cell(j,1).value == all2:
                print all2
                stopper2 = 1
            else:
                j = j+1
                print j
            if worksheet.cell(j,1).value == None:
                boxz=wx.MessageDialog(None,'Wrong Finish point? Wanna see correct choices?','Mistake?',wx.YES_NO)
                answer2=boxz.ShowModal()
                boxz.Destroy
                if answer2 == 5103:
                    boxl2=wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None,'Accepted Finishing point names:','In case of mistake',
                                                ['City1','City2','City3','City4','City5','City6','City7','City8'])
                    if boxl2.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
                        all2=boxl2.GetStringSelection()
                        print all2
                    boxl2.Destroy
                else:
                    print 'how unfortunate'
            if stopper2 == 1:
                sline2 = []
                while worksheet.cell(j,m).value != None:
                    line2 = worksheet.cell(j,m).value
                    sline2.append(line2)
                    m = m + 1
                    print sline2
                    slinestr2 = str(sline2)


        print sline
        print sline2
        t = list(set(sline) & set(sline2))
        print t
        t = t[0]
        t = str(t)
        worksheet2 = sht.worksheet(t)
        print worksheet2
        print worksheet2.cell(2,2)
        i = 2
        j = 2
        iszam = 1
        iszam2 = 1
        stopi = 0
        stopi2 = 0
        km = 0
        while worksheet2.cell(i,2).value != None and stopi != 1:
            if worksheet2.cell(i,2).value == all1:
                iszam = i
                print iszam
                print worksheet2.cell(i,3)
                stopi = 1
            i = i + 1
            print i
        while worksheet2.cell(j,2).value != None and stopi2 != 1:
            if worksheet2.cell(j,2).value == all2:
                iszam2 = j
                print iszam2
                print worksheet2.cell(j,3)
                stopi2 = 1
            j = j + 1
            print j
        if iszam2 < iszam:
            while iszam2 != iszam:
                km = km + int(worksheet2.cell(iszam2+1,3).value)
                iszam2 = iszam2 + 1
            print km

        elif iszam2 > iszam:
            while iszam != iszam2:
                km = km + int(worksheet2.cell(iszam+1,3).value)
                iszam = iszam + 1
            print km
        else:
            km = 0
            print km

        km = str(km)            
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, all1, (20,30))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, slinestr, (80,30))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, all2, (20,60))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, slinestr2, (80,60))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Path =', (20,90))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, t, (80,90))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Distance =', (20,120))
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, km, (80,120))


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()   #runs it
    frame=laci(parent=None,id=-1)   #face of programme
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first place to start IMHO is to find **where** the delay is.

I'd start by moving the code into different functions/methods - that way you'll be able to profile the code and see where the slowness is.

eg. (probably want broken down further than this)

- in the constructor just set up the wx objects
- then have a function that communicates with Google
- and another to write the data to wx.

After that you'll be able to do some profiling either yourself or using the python profiler: (http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). The most important thing is finding what is taking the time and then you will know what needs improving.

My *guess* would be that you don't want to be doing it all remotely but should grab as much as you think you'll need straight away and then do searching locally - as I wouldn't be surprised   if each function call on the spreadsheet results in communication to the server.But I've not used the Google Spreadsheet API so that is ***just a hunch***

Comment: I guess your hunch is good. Today I will continue to develope and later I get back to speed up things. I still have this feeling that it would be faster to do this with graph algorithms but what if I have a spreadsheet with every row beginning with a city name and then only the distance from the previous city, the road name that it belongs to etc (same row, next column), can I still use the table as the base for a Graph? Tamás do you have any suggestions? I really like IGraph features. Somthing tells me it can do more than I think.