# Best way to find shortest path with loading very specific data from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: python, path, wxpython, google-sheets

Now begore you would judge me for FAQ my problem is not so easy as 'the best shortest path algorithm' (at least I think).

I have a Google Spreadsheet.

Every row begins with a town name and it's followed by the nr of roads that go through and by name of of those roads. Something like here bellow:

```
Ex. Spreadsheet / First sheet:
         A    |               B               |     C     |     D     |     E     |
 1  Town name | Number of roads you find here | road name | road name | road name |    
 2  Manchester| 3                             |        M1 |        M2 |        M3 |
 3  Leeds     | 1                             |        M3 |           |           |
 4  Blackpool | 2                             |        M1 |        M2 |           |
```

Now this one Spreadsheet has many worksheets, each for every road name (in my case M1, M2, M3. M1 is the second worksheet since the first one has the content from above. M2 is the third etc)

```
 Ex. Spreadsheet / Second sheet:
       A      |    B      |        C       |      D       |      E     |      F     |
1   This road | Town name | Distance in km | type of road | other road | other road |  
2      M1     | Manchester|       0        |      M2      |     M3     |            | 
3      M1     | Blackpool |      25        |      M2      |            |            |
```

Third sheet is similar, next sheets similar structure. One town can be containd in many sheets depending on how many roads link to it. You can see it from the above example.

The Spreadsheet is not made by me. It's like this. It will not get any better. 
I have no problem pulling the data from the google spreadsheet in the program. Reading spreadsheet data with python is not the question here.

1. What is the best way to write a programme in wxpython/python where a user inputs Starting Town and Finishing Town.
2. The programme will read the spreadsheet and appropriate worksheets.
3. Will find somehow the best path in this jungle of worksheets.
4. It will additionally return the total distance from Starting Town to Finishing town even if the it has to go through maybe more then 2-3 worksheets to get there.
5. Will return results to the users screen in a lovely form :)

I hope you find my problem challenging enough to deserve a questioning.

I beg you for help. Show me the way to go about this very specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What came of your previous attempt:

[Way too slow wxPython application getting data from Google Spreadsheet and User input needs speed up solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725230/way-too-slow-wxpython-application-getting-data-from-google-spreadsheet-and-user)

Did you find what was taking so long? What other issues did you encounter there?

I'm relatively new to stackoverflow but I've seen these style questions, that can be interpreted as *"Could you write this code for me?"*, as being rejected pretty swiftly.

You might want to consider sharing some of the challenges from the above link and explaining a specific problem within the project.

**UPDATED**

1+5:
From the WX point of view, you'll want to keep the UI responsive whilst the search is going on. One way to do this is kick off the searching in a separate thread which calls wx.PostEvent once it has finished. Then in the main wx App you have an event handler which receives the event and processes it. In your case "shows the results on a lovely form".

See here for an example: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: Look Alex, I don't need a single line of code for me. That will definitely not help me in future. What I do want is how to go about it. Should I abandone for example that step by step thingy I have there or should I go for graphs. Should I read that tutorial or should I buy that book. I study. I have a project on my mind. Is it possible to show me the right path or it's not possible? Simple as that. Thanks

Comment: In addition: at this rate I'm not looking anyomre for the answer to the specific question at that link. Do not repost me that. Not helpful at all.

Comment: My comment was not meant to offend - It was more an observation of how the stackoverflow community works and an attempt to help you get more out of it. I've added a pointer for the wx side to the answer above.

Comment: It's not your fault. I'm being very frustrated by the feeling that for weeks now I'm approaching wrong the solution to my task. I do appreciate your answers. I was mostly mad because of my own inability to put the right questions and seek the right answers. I currently believe that for what I want it's probably better to read out the spreadsheet and form a graph from that data. After the graph is formed I may use Dijkstra algorithm to get the right path between towns and with python I might contain additional information to the path.

Comment: At this very moment I'm reading http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html#generating-graphs . Hopefuly on the model explained here I will be able to built a code using IGraph for the thing I want to do. I think I just need the feeling that I make progress. That I read the right stuff. Now it's all frustrating and time is passing over me. I will now try to concantrate on the algorithm and later I will get back to UI with wxPython.

Comment: To describe how I feel about my project: it's like you kind of know how to swim and than they grap you and throw you in the middle of the Pacific Ocean :D

Comment: Finally I made a very good use of the link you've recommended me ( http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks ). The last example. The very simple one was invaluable to my wx.Python UI :D Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end :)